# How hot is the core of a star just before it collapses to form a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, temperature, astrophysics, stellar-evolution

Is the core of a star still hot as the star collapses under its own gravity?

Answer (score 0):

Regard temperatures in the life cycle of a core collapse supernova, Wikipedia has that info:

[image]

Of course, when the collapse to neutron star occurs, the core temperature can exceed 100 Billion Kelvin. The whole core becomes hot enough to emit all three generations of neutrinos as blackbody radiation.

Now if the core goes straight to a blackhole, the center must get much hotter, be way may never see it (https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2020/popular-information/):

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm conflating some ideas here, but aren't temperatures of black holes inversely proportional to its mass? So wouldn't they be on the colder side?

Comment: normal blackholes are much colder than the CMB